# Sync website browsing to another machine?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, browser, synchronization

Is it possible to have a website displayed on two seperate machines but to syncronise the users input on either machine to the other?

Basically any anchor clicks, image zooms, javascript pop out menus etc need to also occur on the other users screen and vice versa.

In my case the site will be developed in c#.NET but how would one approach something like this, would you use javascript or a database or some other method?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use off-the-shelf desktop sharing tools (almost each company build at least one)...

Comment: The problem is that both machines need to control each other one being an iPad and the other a windows based machine, there doesnt seem to be an off the shelf solution?

Comment: I can see it being doable for some stuff like text input, clicks and anything else jquery can recognize. You'll JSON it back to the server and send it to a different active session where you can pick it up and apply it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent a long time looking into this I've found a solution, SignalR - http://signalr.net/ for ASP.NET allows you to do exactly what I require, I won't go into detail here as the post would become huge but for anyone wanting to do the same in future then visit http://signalr.net/ and have a read, it's amazing technology!